# <li> - transfer to a new line in layout

Tags: html, css

I use < li > for every shop element to show buttons.
but every < li > begins on new line so i use float: left to avoid this.

html:

```
<div id="main" >    
    <li><div id="block"><img src="blabla"></div></li>
    <li><div id="block"><img src="blabla"></div></li>
    <li><div id="block"><img src="blabla"></div></li>
    <li><div id="block"><img src="blabla"></div></li>
    <li><div id="block"><img src="blabla"></div></li>
</div>
```

css:

```
#main{
    margin: 0px auto;
    width:940px;
    }


#block {
    height:286px;
    width:312px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    vertical-align:middle;
    display:table-cell;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    }

li {
        list-style-type:none;
        vertical-align:top;
        float:left;
        white-space: nowrap;
        width:313px;
        }
```

but

I have [image]

I need:[image]

Comment: You have multiple elements with the same ID. That can cause all kinds of problems. You should be using a class instead. And ID is supposed to be a unique identifier for a single element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give #main overflow:auto and enclose your LI elements within a UL tag.

Also you are using the same ID multiple times which should not be done. You should use a class instead of an ID if you want to use it like this. An ID is a unqiue tag that can only be used once per page.

Answer (score 1):

first try to make your code validate.Your html code is not valid at all.Put all your `<li>` inside `<ul>...</ul>` tags.
Don't use the `same id for multiple times`.You can use `class instead of that at multiple of times.`